# Raster algebra on multiple bands in R Growing degree days calculation

Tags: r, stack, raster, modeling, r-raster

So I am building a 30-year average growing degree days raster from the daily min and max temperature for North America. The input data is composed of 60 rasters, 30 tmax, and 30 tmin . Each of those rasters consists of 365 bands (one for each day). The calculation for GDD is fairly simple it is `((tmax-tmin))/2)-10`. The problem is I can't seem to find a way for all the bands and raster to be calculated together.

My initial plan was to stack all tmin rasters and all tmax rasters and subtract them together. But in that case, only the first band (day 1) gets computed. Is there any ways to do the operation without having to extract all bands one by one.

```
library(raster)

tmax <- stack("C:/gddtmax")
tmin <- stack("C:/gddtmin")
average <- ((tmax-tmin)/2)-10
```

Comment: hi @PhilippeTremblay, I am trying to calculate something similar. Please, is here your base temperature 10? I.e. then you calculate the sum of the positive temperature differences? if is is sum over 100 days of positive difference, can you call it temperature sum (100 dd)?

Answer (score 2):

Your example works fine for me.

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
tmax <- brick(f) / 10
tmin <- tmax - 10
```

`tmax` and `tmin` each have three layers

```
avg <- ((tmax-tmin)/2)-10
```

And `avg` also has three layers

```
avg
#class       : RasterBrick 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : in memory
#names       : red, green, blue 
#min values  :  -5,    -5,   -5 
#max values  :  -5,    -5,   -5
```

**EDIT**
It looks like the problem was due to a memory management bug (fixed in version 2.7-3). Here are two work-arounds.

Use `overlay` (which also allows you to specify an output filename)

```
avg <- overlay(tmin, tmax, fun=function(x, y){ ((y-x)/2)-10 })
```

Or use `rasterOptions`

```
rasterOptions(todisk=TRUE)
avg <- ((tmax-tmin)/2)-10
rasterOptions(todisk=FALSE)
```

Comment: The problem is that my rasters composing tmin and tmax are each composed of other rasters with 365 layers inside of them. So the structure of the tmax stack is 20 rasters with 365 layer inside of each of them. Basically a stack of stacks.

Comment: I do not see why that would be a problem. Please provide an example

Comment: You were right after building some tests rasters, I realized everything works properly. The issue is actually the size of the dataset 120Gb , R being unable the process vectors that are larger than 1.4Gb. Would there be a way to extract only a few bands(days) at a time and then compute the results ?

Comment: size should not a problem. If it is, you are probably making a mistake. Please show the code where this happens.  In rare corner-cases you may need to change the memory settings with rasterOptions()

Comment: Load rasters
`tmax <- stack("daymet_v3_tmax_1990_na.nc4")`
`tmin <- stack("Cdaymet_v3_tmin_1990_na.nc4")`
Verified #layers
`> nlayers(tmax)
[1] 365`
`> nlayers(tmin)
[1] 365`
calculate the GDD
`> GDD <- ((tmax+tmin)/2)-10`
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.7 Gb`

Comment: I think I found out why this happens. A bug ((not checking properly for the memory requirements in the Arith group generic function for Raster* Raster* signature)). Will be fixed in next version. I will update the answer